# Handling numerous parallel requests for modifying license count in a nosql db via nodejs based microservice

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I have a node based microservice which is responsible for updating the license items in a nosql database, I have deployed 2 replicas of the microservice attached to a load balancer in a kubernetes cluster. The updation of the license count is done via REST request received to the microservice. Considering that we receive numerous requests in parallel, How do we make sure all the requests work in a sequential manner and deliver a response to the API request? (Working with parallel execution is a problem as when more requests are received we need to make sure the initial requests are handled before)
[image]

Comment: I assume the load balancer is in front of some EC2 services?

You could have them all send the data, with a group id, to an SQS that then updates the nosql db.  If they were instead of Ec2s, lambdas they would handle this automatically on the back end with concurrency pretty well - unless you are receiving hundreds a second it would pretty much be OK. (whether that is in spec for you or not i cannot say) But with the load balancer, and Ec2s - if you can generate a group id that would be unique but also recreatable (so calls that need to be together in parallel, remain so), an SQS would work

Comment: I understand that queuing mechanism is an asynchronous process while rest api is a synchronous process. How would I respond to the request

Comment: if your use case is that you may end up with multiple calls to the api that have to be done in order and their response relies on the task to be done, but the parallel is a thing in the back end, you may have to rethink your design choices.  You can, theoretically, set up a lambda in front of the load balancer that also waits and polls for the job being done in the back end - another solution would be to use a Step Function but im not sure you can include Ec2 clusters behind a load balancer in a step function.